# How to sort_by using class method Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, sorting

I'm trying to rank instances using a class method:

```
@sorted_datsk_hpe = all_datsk_hpe.sort_by { |hpe| Hpe.datsk_point_count(hpe) }
```

which takes me here:

```
def self.datsk_point_count(hpe)
    points = 0
    if hpe.gen_ac != ""
      if hpe.gen_aa != nil
        points += hpe.gen_aa.to_i * hpe.gen_acd
      else
        points += hpe.gen_amc.to_i * hpe.gen_acd
      end
    else
      (1..10).each do |num|
        if hpe["ad_c_#{num}"] != ""
          if hpe["ad_c_#{num}_available"] != nil
            points += hpe["ad_c_#{num}_available"].to_i * hpe["ad_c_#{num}_discount"]
          else
            points += hpe["ad_c_#{num}_max_capacity"].to_i * hpe["ad_c_#{num}_discount"]
          end
        end
      end
    end
    points
  end
```

which gives me

```
TypeError: String can't be coerced into Integer
    from app/models/hpe.rb:420:in `+'
    from app/models/hpe.rb:420:in `datsk_point_count'
    from (irb):30:in `block in irb_binding'
    from (irb):30:in `sort_by'
    from (irb):30
```

but if i run the class method on its own with a single instance, it works, so I must be doing sort_by wrong?

Comment: Perhaps one of the `all_datsk_hpe` entries isn't what you expect it to be. Which line is 420? What exactly is in `hpe` when your `TypeError` is raised?

Comment: as @mu says; I'd suggest you look in your "..._discount" columns (or force a to_i on them)

Comment: thank you - 420 points to ```points += hpe.gen_amc.to_i * hpe.gen_acd```, and all data types correspond.  what is in hpe is a good question; I put binding.pry on first line in class method, but it doesn't reach it before TypeError.  in the sort_by, all_datsk_hpe is an array of Hpe instances, and I was assuming hpe was an instance getting thrown to the class method, but

Comment: ... apparently you have to restart console if you modify model code :(  I appreciate the help tho, ty

Comment: I would do a `p hpe.gen_aa` and `p hpe.gen_acd` and also a `p hpe.gen_aa.to_i` just before the offending statement, to see what datatypes we have here. Perhaps the `to_i` is implemented incorrectly and yields a String instead of an Integer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code was right, I just wasn't aware that model code changes requires restarting console, similar to needing to refresh the page when modifying javascript etc.

This may not be exactly accurate as I am novice, but restarting the console resolved the issue.

Comment: Welcome. You seem to have answered your own question, which you can also accept (and helps to 'close' this one).